# System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, suspend

```
    public static void Dispatch(Action action)
    {

        var actionResult = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);

        while (!actionResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            FlushEventQueue();                
            Thread.Sleep(DispatcherHelper.WaitInternal);
        }
        action.EndInvoke(actionResult);
    }

    //Flush Event
    internal static void FlushEventQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            Dispatcher dispatcher = WpfUtils.GetDispatcher();
            dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, DispatcherHelper.FlushAction);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    //Get Dispatcher 
    public static Dispatcher GetDispatcher()
    {  
        //set Dispatcher on Application OnStartUp event
        // AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("Dispatcher", this.Dispatcher);
        Dispatcher dispatcher = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("Dispatcher") as Dispatcher;
        if (dispatcher == null)
        {
            dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        }

        return dispatcher;
    }
```

I've caught an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot perform this operation while
>   dispatcher processing is suspended.    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation
>   operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at Mvvm.Dispatching.DispatcherHelper.FlushEventQueue()
>   at Mvvm.Dispatching.DispatcherHelper.Dispatch(Action action)

Comment: if you want to raise an event from non-UI thread, then it is not necessary to get `Dispatcher` object as WPF automatically raises `PropertyChanged` event on UI thread. Just try to remove `Dispatcher` object and see what happens.

Comment: while I calling web service on non-UI thread, I want to refresh UI